# How can I simulate a website loading slowly?

Tags: tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I simulate a slow connection for page load?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/861/how-can-i-simulate-a-slow-connection-for-page-load)

I found some old treaths about this topic but is there a new/working way to slow down the loading of a website (local websever) to a predefined speed, as if it were, for example, on a dial-up connection?
I didn't find a good working one... (On Windows).

It would be nice if it's a Firefox add-on/plugin.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean, simulate using a website over a slow connection, like dial-up?

Comment: @paulmorriss: yes :-)

Comment: @paulmorriss: You have edited my post... i have no problem with that, but i don't get it why a thanks or a smily isn't appropriate... how come?

Comment: @Nomistake see [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @paulmorriss: ok