# Any tools to limit my bandwidth to 56k to test how long it takes to load my website?

Tags: throttling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I simulate a slow connection for page load?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/861/how-can-i-simulate-a-slow-connection-for-page-load)

Which software or method could I use to limit my connection speed to 56k or other amounts, and load up a webpage I am hosting to see how long it would take to access for users with a slow connection?

Comment: Do visitors really connect to your website on dialup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some tools to artificially limit bandwidth, sorted by platform:

#### Mac, Linux, and Windows (Java-based)

- [Sloppy](http://www.dallaway.com/sloppy/)

#### Mac only

- [Slowy](http://slowyapp.com/)
- [Network Link Conditioner](http://mattgemmell.com/2011/07/25/network-link-conditioner-in-lion/)

#### Linux

- [Netem](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem)

#### Web apps

- [Throttle](https://github.com/dmolsen/Throttle)

Answer (score 1):

For windows, you can also install NetLimiter to limit bandwidth globally or per app.